# dynamic class generation

Tags: matlab, reflection

How to dynamically create a class from its content?

In fact I've create a kind of Matlab engine classes instantiation and execution, in which I can list all class files (*.m) in a directory, instantiate them (with 'eval(clasnname)') and use theses objects.

Now I want to change the file content of theses files "on the fly", and then, instantiate them and use these new objects.

So I've written a function to read the content of file into a string, replace/add some contents into this string and... I don't know how to create an object (instance of a class) from this string (which contains 'classdef myClass < myMotherClass \n ... end'). (I know that I can create a new file on my filesystem with this string content and then use eval(...) as I've already done, but I try to do this without create new physical file).

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible in MATLAB, unlike in a pure object-oriented programming language like Ruby. If it were, then there would be some way of building a `meta.class` object, but there's not.

I think that writing a `classdef` file is your only option. You may need to programmatically call `rehash` in order to get it to load the new definition and if there are existing objects using the old definition, then it won't load the new definition at all until you clear everything.

I suppose the real question is "Why do you need to do this?"

**Aside**: Use `feval` rather than `eval` to create instances of your new class.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I must write a classdef file. So I've try this.. writting the content into the appropriate file, loading it via eval(classname) and then... deleting the file; and it's don't work. Matlab really need that te file exist when using the class (why? why it don't load the classdef into the memory? it must parse and parse and parse... the file every time a function of the class is called?). So I've just deleted the newest files at then end of my program.

Comment: It needs to have the file present so that it can check that nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB does allow you to modify object instances at runtime by adding [dynamic properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/bq08quy.html), but you cannot add methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can create a dynamic class in matlab, by subclassing to dynamicprops, and you can even create an entire class from a string, like a file or JSON or whatever. See my example [myDynamicClass](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35404-mydynamicclass/content/myDynamicClass.m) on [FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)